# RegEx for two characters followed by four digits

Tags: regex

Can you help me please with an regular expression that will have
4 digits and 2 characters

I wrote this

```
^([0-9]{4})(s*([a-zA-Z]{2}))?$
```

But when I validate it also accepts only 4 digits.

Comment: I think you want to use `\s` instead of `s` to match 0+ whitespace characters.

Comment: `(\s*([a-zA-Z]{2}))` ..remove `?` and use `\s`

Answer (score 0):

Your `?`, means that the previous item, is optional.

This means that it can match "3421" as well as "2323som".

---

**Regular expressions are greedy**, so they will try to match "2378som" instead of just "2378" if you call them on "2378som". The reason that you are not getting matched, is probably `s*`. This means zero or more "s". If you mean spaces, then you should use `(\s)*`.

Thus it should become

```
^([0-9]{4})((\s)*([a-zA-Z]{2}))?$
```

Check the [unit tests here](https://regex101.com/r/fW8dG1/1) to understand what this matches.

Be careful, that it matches only what `\s` represents in the environment of your regex (it might not include tabs or other kinds of spaces).

---

What you have written, is trying to match against the character "s" zero or more times, thus this sting: "1234sab" is valid, as is "1234ab". If you meant to match "1234 ab", the reason that only "1234" is returned, is that "s" is missing, so it's looking for 2 characters. You have provided 3 characters " ab" (space + a + b), outside of the range `[a-zA-Z]`. Thus since the second item is not matched (has 3 characters you wanted 2 and space is not A-Z), your `?` ignores the second item, and returns the first, ergo "1234".